# sql azure time out on SQL large tables

Tags: .net, sql, azure, cloud

im using sql azure for analyzing data in big tables (130 mln records).

The problem is that when I try to run a query (which locally takes for example 12 hrs) on azure i get an error:

*Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.*

Is there any way to prevent it from timeing out and perform long time sql queries on azure ?

Comment: Azure does not honor SqlCommand.CommandTimeout?  0 is no timeout.

Answer (score 3):

You are not going to be able to perform a query that uses up that many resources inside Windows Azure SQL Database. This runs in an environment that is shared by many users. This kind of query would cause the other users to suffer. Last documentation I saw limited a connection to 5 minutes.

You may however spin up a SQL Server instance in a Windows Azure VM. There are even images available in the gallery for this. In this case, you have control over the entire VM and may use as many resources as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use SQL Azure for querying, I would recommend the new "Premium reservations" feature that is in preview mode.  This gives you SQL Azure with a dedicated reservation and removes some limits like long running queries, throttling and max log size.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/sql-databases/sign-up-for-sql-database-premium/

I have large tables with complex queries...(20 million rows)
- ensure covering indexes are present
- READ UNCOMMITED or NOLOCK hints are your friend